# Getting/sending some information from Telegram at bot startup, after Application build() but before run_polling()?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm a bit confused about this because Im new to python-telegram,-bot, and most examples online dont reflect the v20 changes for Updater and asyncio.

The relevant snippet of code is:

```
def main() -> None:
    persistence_object = PicklePersistence(filepath=persistent_data_file_path)
    application = (
        ApplicationBuilder()
        .token(bot_token)
        .persistence(persistence=persistence_object)
        .post_init(post_init_handler)
        .post_stop(post_stop_handler)
        .build()
        )
    application.run_polling()

async def post_init_handler(application: Application) -> None:
    print("init")
    bot_id=application.bot.bot.id
    # Needed: Code snippet here (details below)
    # It produces a list, which is sent as a raw text private message to a static defined user_id

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The missing code snippet obtains a list of all chats the bot is in (private, group, supergroup), with some key information about each (see below) and then send that info to a specific user_id as a private message. It doesnt enter polling until that's succeeded. The info it collates and sends is:

```
(chat id,
 username/title of the chat,
 chat type (private, group etc),
 is the bot the owner of the chat? (if a group/channel),
 bot's admin rights in the chat (if a group/channel and admin)
)
```

So a typical output sent would be:

```
123456,@fred99,private,(ignored),(ignored)
872981,@technogeek_chat,supergroup,True,(rights data)
(etc)
```

I cant figure out the correct way to get and send this data at bot startup.

- **CORRECT API CALL/S TO USE?**
  All the examples I can find, assume their actions are done reactively within some callback handler as a result of a polled received update, or if done initially, the example uses older Updater/dispatcher techniques not applicable in v20.
  I * think * from the Transition guide to v20 that `application.create_task` could be the correct answer but if so I dont have a good example to rely on, how I'd use it for this.
- **CORRECT PLACEMENT FOR API CALL/S?**
  I tried to move the code to between `application...build()` and before `run_polling()`, but the assignment `bot_id=application.bot.bot.id` failed and I couldnt get that to work. It wanted it initialized, I think, but I wasnt sure what was correct, or which was the more correct place of the two for this code snippet, and left it within `post_init_handler()` which at least * seemed * to work?
- **GETTING DATA FOR THE CALL/S?**
  I tried to find code to list the chats the bot is in. The only links were to the example "chatmemberbot.py", and that code doesnt actually detect what chats the bot is in.  It relies on adding and removing from a manually maintained list based on updates. Which could potentially desync from actual chats it's in, in some situations (bugs, persist store deleted/corrupted/old store restored, shutdown prior to final flush in the past, ...)  and the bot would never know its list wasn't correct.

What's the correct way to do this, please? Is it possible to have an actual example - simplified if it's easier - how it should be done, as I've scoured the docs and can't figure it from those?

Help much appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CORRECT API CALL/S TO USE?

To simply make a request to Telegram, all you need is a `Bot` instance. Please have a look at PTB [Introduction](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API) for some examples. Note that you already have a `Bot` instance available via `application.bot`, so there is no need to build one on yowr own. You can simply use it via e.g.

```
async def post_init_handler(application):
    await application.bot.send_message(text="Hello World", chat_id=123)
```

[`Application.create_task`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.create_task) is rather unrelated to making requests to Telegram but is a simple convenience function for asynchronous programming with PTB.

#### CORRECT PLACEMENT FOR API CALL/S?

`post_init` is the correct place. This callback is there precisely to run custom logic before the polling of updates starts. This is also explained in the docs of [`Application.run_polling`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.run_polling)

#### GETTING DATA FOR THE CALL/S?

> I tried to find code to list the chats the bot is in

This simply does not exist in the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) and keeping track manually is the only option. The chat member updates you already found are the most reliable way to do this.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thanks! 2 questions.  In the 1st snippet, any chance of an edit to the post_init example to show it get/set some arbitrary info for user 123456 or chat 123456, rather than the more common "post a message to {chat_id}" use-case? Thats a lot less demo'ed in most examples Ive seen, a clear example would help a lot.  On the 3rd point, the bot I have aims to patrol specific chats, and leave any others. Am I right that it could join its list of chats on post_init (wont hurt if already there), and later, if it notices its in any unwanted chats, leave them then? Hence no need to track chats its in?

Comment: Also maybe worth adding a note on those last 2, to the docs? (On the 2nd of 3, Even tho its in run_polling the choice of the 2 isnt stated as a preference, so its conceivable both have pros and cons unless explicitly stated)

Comment: TBH I don't really understand your follow up questions. I recommend that you join the PTB community on [Telegram](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup) to ask your questions there.